For the sequence $a_1=101, a_2=10101 ,a_3=1010101....$ so on, finding when $a_k$ is composite(all base $10$)
Problem:
Consider the sequence,$a_1=101, a_2=10101 ,a_3=1010101,$(all base $10$) and so on. Then $a_k$ is a composite number when,
(A) if and only if $k\ge2$ and $11$ divides $10^{k+1} + 1$;
(B) if and only if $k\ge2$ and $11$ divides $10^{k+1} - 1$;
(C) if and only if $k\ge2$ and $k - 2$ is divisible by $3$
(D) if and only if $k\ge2$.
My attempt:
Observe that $a_3=101.100^2+101=101(100^2+1)$ and so similarly for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ 
a_{2m+1}=1+100+100^2+100^3.....+100^{2m+1}
$$
$$
\implies a_{2m+1}=(1+100)+100^2(1+100)+100^4(100+1).....+100^{2m}(100+1)=101.(\sum_{i=0}^{2m} 100^i)
$$
So, for $k \ge 2$ and $k$ being odd, $a_k$ is composite, also,
$$
10^{2m+2}-1=(10-1)(\sum_{i=0}^{i=2m+1}10^i)=9(1+10+10^2....10^{2m+1})=9((1+10)+(10^2+10^3)...(10^{2m}+10^{2m+1}))
$$
$$
=9.11.(1+10^2+10^4...10^{2m})\implies 11|10^{k+1}-1 \text{ for k being odd natural number}
$$
So, when $11|10^{k+1}-1$ then $a_k$ is a composite number, which makes me think option (B) must be correct because option (A) is incorrect as this condition makes $a_k$ composite and $a_3$ disapproves option(C), as it is composite then the only two options left are (A) and (D), now (A) can't be correct because $a_8$ would be divisible by $3$ due to its divisibility criteria and so option(D) must be accurate but I can't prove it. Please help!

I want proof of $a_k$ being composite for even k, but an exception would also work.

Have you found a single prime in the sequence other than $101$?

As a suggestion:  consider the closed formula for the sum of your geometric series  Also:  I suggest indicating that these are intended to be base $10$ numbers.  I assumed they were binary at first (doesn't really change the answer).

@lulu No I only checked $a_4$ and I apologise for the mistake of not clarifying that they were base 10 numbers

I suggest checking more of them.  Wolfram Alpha is a good way to do that.

First thing that caught my eye: what are $99a_1, 99a_2, 99a_3 ; ? ;  $

@lulu what's with the closed formula, I have expanded the sum of GP here but I don't know about the closed formula for the sum of geometric series

next    : what are $1 +99a_1, ; ; 1+ 99a_2, ; ; 1+ 99a_3 ; ? ;  $

geometric series.

@will-jagy all of them are powers of 10 but what are you trying to prove?

Rex, I really want you to do it;  this could be called "inquiry based,"   my point is that you really can do this yourself. Powers of ten, yes. What are the exponents?  There is something obvious about them

@lulu I understand what you meant but I am not going anywhere with the formula of sum of gp and please detail if you think $100^{2n+1}-1$ has factors other than $11, 9,1$ and itself.

@will-jagy can you confirm that the problem is correct?

@will-jagy the exponents are even numbers

Do you know anything useful about factoring $x^2-1$?

@lulu yeah, but just that its $(x+1)(x-1)$

Good; rather than just powers of ten, you have powers of $100.$   What is the simplest factoring of $100^k -1 ; ? ;  $  It is a difference of squares

You have the sum wrong. If $S_n=1+10^2+\cdots +10^{2n}$ then $S_n=\frac {10^{2n+2}-1}{10^2-1}$.  The common raio is $100=10^2$, not $10$.

Ohh it was too obvious  thanks @will-jagy

also thanks @lulu

@lulu can you point exactly where is the sum wrong?

The numerator ought to be $10^{2n+2}-1$.  You seem to have something different, but perhaps I am misreading.

but where is the fraction @lulu, there is no numerator and as far your sum is concerned I wrote $100^m-1$ but never mentioned the actual value of sum, if you have any doubts please clarify

I don't understand.  The sum $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^nr^k=\frac {r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$.  Here, $r=100$.  Of course there is a fraction.

but where did I write it ,there is no fraction in the problem and my attempt and when you gave me your proposal to use the sum of gp I used $100^{2n+1}-1$ because it was the numerator and I nowhere mentioned the denominator @lulu thanks for the proposal to use formula for gp sum

I think we are going in circles.  In an earlier comment, you referedm to $100^{2m+1}$ but I don't understand why.  In your posted solution, you appear to be only considering the case of even indices, but the parity of the index is irrelevant. The common ratio is $100=10^2$ so the relevant exponent is always even.

Ok you are right I was wrong in my approach so I apologise.

Hint: How might you generalize $101010101 = 41 \times 271 \times 9091$?

Thanks @aschepler but I have already posted the solution

As per the suggestion of @lulu and @will-jagy, this is the proof for $k$ being even,
Let $k=2m$,where $m\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
1+100+100^2....+100^{2m}=\frac{100^{2m+1}-1}{99}=\frac{10^{2(2m+1)}-1}{99}=\frac{10^{2m+1}-1}{9}.\frac{10^{2m+1}+1}{11}
$$
and so the above sum is composite.
